# CORS header error with socket.io and nodejs at apache2

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am just earning to impliment socket.io inside laravel. but I am getting `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MM9_PhA. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).` error.

Below is my node.js file:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();
redis.subscribe('test-channel', function (err, count) {
});
redis.on('message', function (channel, message) {
    io.set('origins', 'http://localhost:3001');
    console.log('Message Recieved: ' + message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});
http.listen(3001, function () {
    io.set('origins', 'http://localhost:3001');
    console.log('Listening on Port 3001');
});
```

please help me to find why it is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the headers in your app.js.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3001");

  next();
});
```